# What's the best way to modify an inherited array in javascript without changing its parent

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, inheritance, properties

I want to make an object that inherits from an other object. In constructing the descendant, i want to push some items to an inherited array without changing the parentobject.

Say I have an object called basket:

```
function Basket(){
}
```

Then i fill it like this:

```
Basket.prototype {
    “price”: 5,
    “contents” : [“apple”, “orange”, “grape”]
}
```

Now i want to extend this. I want to add some properties and change some. I did this:

```
function BigBasket(){
    this.price = 6; // change a property. This goes well, when an instance is created, price is still 5 in prototype and also in instances of Basket and it is 6 in the instance that is created from this descendant.
    this.greetingcard = “Congratulations” // add a property. Goes well
```

Now i want to add an item to the contents-property but only in the descendant instances.

This goes wrong:

```
    this.contents.push(“banana”);
```

It seems this.contents contains a reference to the array of the prototype so when pushing a banana to it, means that instances of both Bigbasket and Basket get a banana in their contents as well. Therefore i first made a copy of the Basket.contents (the parent contents) like this:

```
    this.contents = Object.getPrototypeOf(this).contents.slice(); // seems __proto__ is deprecated, so using getPrototypeOf here and then pushed the banana:
    this.contents.push(‘banana’);
}
```

This seems to be working, but is this the right way? I know array is an object as well, so i tried this:

```
    this.contents = Object.create(Basket.prototype.contents);
    this.contents.push('banana');
```

This works too and seems a more generic way. Furthermore in Chrome the item that was pushed last was a property of only the descendant while the rest of the array-items were properties of the prototype. Seems elegant to me.

Still, this looks a bit clumsy to me. Am i doing this all wrong? Tried to find out but couldn’t find anything on the topic of array’s in extending objects. Is there a way of making descendants where all properties are copied and not referenced when instanciated?

Thanks!

Comment: A tip to begin with. Never have object in prototype. Prototype is best suited for static values which are not likely to change.

Comment: When you access `this.contents`, it will look for the property directly on the object. It is not found. Then, it will look for the property in its `[[Prototype]]`. Here it is `Basket.prototype.contents`. So, it will push to that array. In the second scenario, there is an *own* `contents` property, so it never looks in the `[[Prototype]]`

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

- Instead of putting `price` and `content` on prototype, make them as properties of `Basket`.
- Inherit `BigBasket` and set its prototype as instance of `Basket`. This will give you access to properties of Basket.
- Define a private variable `content` in `BigBasket` whose job will be to maintain the child's content.
- Add a setter function to mutate this variable

  - `addContent`: Add new values to child's content
  - `removeContentByIndex`: to remove value based on index.
  - `getContent`: This will return a copy of `content` to nullify side effect. This will also allow you to have custom definition of content. In this case, its own content + parent's content

  this will allow you to define an API to communicate with content and also allows you to create a restrict data that is exposed. Exposing everything can cause issues. Exposing what is required is always better.

**Note:** Having objects on prototype can cause issues as objects will have side effect. You should use Parent's values as default values only.

```js
function Basket() {
  this.price = 5;
  this.contents = ["apple", "orange", "grape"]
}

function BigBasket() {
 const content = [];
  this.price = 6;
  this.greetingcard = "Congratulations";
 this.addContent = function(value) {
   content.push(value);
  }
  this.removeContentByIndex = function(index) {
   content.splice(index, 1);
  }
  this.getContents = function() {
   return [].concat(this.__proto__.contents, content);
  }
}

BigBasket.prototype = new Basket();

const bb1 = new BigBasket();
const bb2 = new BigBasket();
bb1.addContent('banana');
console.log(bb1.getContents(), bb2.getContents())
```

Comment: **Note:** If you think this answer has anything missing or has any incorrect information, please share your views as comment along with your vote.